# highlighting / error not working for "remote" validation

Tags: javascript, jquery-validate

I am using [jquery-validate](/questions/tagged/jquery-validate) with Bootstrap 4 and chargify, which required a bit of customization at initialization time. The visual customizations and submitHandler don't seem to be issues. However, I am also using the "remote" option ([documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/)), which is where my problem seems to lie. My current initialization is this:

```
// note: app.form is a cached jQuery object wrapping the form in question
app.form.validate({
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        if (form.valid()) {
            chargify.token(
              form,
              function success(token) {
                  document.querySelector('#chargifyToken').value = token;
                  form.submit();
              },
              function error(err) {
                  console.log('token ERROR - err: ', err);
              }
            );
        }
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
    },
    errorClass: 'invalid-feedback',
    errorElement: 'div',
    rules: {
        "subDomain": {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2,
            remote: '../servlet/CheckSubDomainServlet'
        }
    }
});
```

The whole initialization is provided for the sake of completeness, but I'm not convinced any of it is relevant.

**The Problem**

As I check on my subDomain, if I blur on the empty field it correctly highlights the field and shows the "field required" error in an appropriate div. If I enter one character and blur, I get the correct behaviour for the "minlength" rule. So I can be relatively certain that the HTML itself and the highlight/error behaviour is correct.

But when the "remote" URL is finally invoked, the behaviour is not as expected. Regardless of pass or fail, the field stays highlighted with `".is-invalid"`, which also hides the feedback div. Regardless of its hidden state, the `".invalid-feedback"` div is also not populated with a message.

The returned JSON comes in one of two formats. First example is fail, second is pass:

```
{
  "subDomain":"SubDomain can't be only numeric"
}
```

or

```
{
  "subDomain":true
}
```

Now, the [documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) isn't GREAT for the remote option, but I THINK that's the shape the return should take. Their own linked examples seem to show this signature.

In case I'm still not being clear: what's missing is that when the remote service returns a pass, the field should be un-highlighted. When it returns a fail, the field should be highlighted, and the custom message passed by the service should be displayed in the error field.

---

**UPDATE**

I believe it is actually the response JSON that's messing things up. If I look directly at the validate source code, it wants to see if `response == true || response || response == "true"` for the truth part. Which is weird, because it also documents this: "The serverside response must be a JSON string that must be "true" for valid elements, and can be "false", undefined, or null for invalid elements".

Of course, there's no such thing as JSON string without a key to match it to, and the documentation doesn't say what the key should be. I extrapolated by looking at the return messages from their sample pages. So now I'm not sure what the response should be, or how their sample pages are actually working successfully. I feel like it would "work" if my response was html/text in the format "true" or "Some message" without JSON at all.

**UPDATE 2: SOLUTION**

In case anyone ever stumbled across this, the answer is in Sparky's comment, and matches my suspicion in the first update: the server side was returning incorrectly formatted responses.

Response should be in application/text, and the entire response body should contain either:

```
"true"
```

or

```
"Some custom error message"
```

With this done, everything works. It turns out that the documentation is fine, too, but I was thrown by the term "JSON-formatted string" which really just means "wrapped properly in double-quotes and with only valid characters." I thought it meant that a whole JSON object was needed.

Comment: BTW - I wrote that paragraph of the `remote` documentation.  Show your server-side code.  You want `"true"` as a string, not a boolean.  If it was PHP, the correct response for passing validation would be `echo json_encode("true")` OR `echo "true"`.  For failing validation, echoing anything else would cause a fail.  Echoing a JSON encoded string causes a validation failure, but the string only becomes the custom validation message when it is JSON encoded.

Comment: Thanks again for your time, Sparky. The server side code is nothing interesting to look at. I'm only replying with {"key":"value"} as JSON because of a combination of the docs referring to JSON, and the sample itself. The back end handed over the servlet to me, so I can shape it however I wish now. Returning "true" or "message" in application/text worked dandy. AFAICT, it was just a misunderstanding of the documentation.

Comment: You're welcome.  Might be better to post answer below and accept it.  Also, keep in mind that if the server-side code is PHP and response is a string, it **must** use `echo json_encode("custom error message")` or the custom message will be ignored.  No idea what server-side language you're using, or why a simple string works for you, but that's the reason I think it's very relevant to include something about the server side code in your OP and/or answer.

Comment: Hey, it's really your answer, but I'll do it. ;-) The server-side is in Java. The response is nothing more than using a built-in post method with "any old string" (wrapped in double quotes) as the response body. There's nothing special about PHP's json_encode other than ensuring the double-quotes and sanitizing invalid characters. That's why returning a simple string works fine. We're not bothering to do the sanitization, but looking at jQuery.validate's remote method, all it's doing it grabbing the returned body. What I'm confused about are the samples <shrug>.

Comment: I've been making small corrections to the jQuery Validate documentation as time permits.  In the case of `remote`, the one sentence that explained it was grammatically messy and very misleading.  I re-wrote that into something with more explanation.  But I agree, there are still some code examples in there that seem unconventional and/or incorrect.  All I can do is fork and submit my pull requests, and eventually maybe approved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it easier to find, here's the answer, derived from Sparky's comments in the original question:

Response should be in application/text, and the entire response body should contain either:

```
"true"
```

or

```
"Some custom error message"
```

The double-quotes are required, and it should not be any sort of complete JSON object. With this done, everything works. It turns out that the documentation is fine, too, but I was thrown by the term "JSON-formatted string" which really just means "wrapped properly in double-quotes and with only valid characters." I thought it meant that a whole JSON object was needed.

Our Java code eventually does its internal validation, and already has access to an HttpServletResponse class. It then just makes a PrintWriter based on HttpServletResponse.getWriter() and writes to it:

```java
PrintWriter out = null;

// ... later ...
// "response" was passed in as type HttpServletResponse
out = response.getWriter();

// out is just a buffer for what gets dumped into response body
out.println(resultingString);
out.flush();
out.close();
```